# Unable to execute dex: Java heap space: have increased Xmx values and still receive error

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

New to android and I'm attempting to use google maps api v2 in my app.  I receive the message 'Unable to execute dex: Java heap space'.  Like all the posts say, I've increased the Xmx values, 512, 1024, 8000, in the eclipse.ini file and app still crashes. It seems that increasing this value is working for everyone else.

eclipse.ini

```
-startup
```

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize512M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
c:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826

### -XX:MaxPermSize=512M

Manifest

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBTld_xjcyXpHO1Dl1CrdL817o_IZ_VTHQ" />


    <activity android:name="com.example.dcparksnew.library.google_play_services_lib" />
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/maptext"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: I once encountered this and the only way it went away was using 2512m:  --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
2512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
2512m

Comment: Wished it would have worked, but it didn't.